# C# Get all available FontFamily

Tags: c#, loops, fonts, font-face, font-family

I have an input box, and people type a font in and it saves what they type as a JPEG.  All works fine.  But when they type a font name like '`times new roman`' it has to be capitalised properly to '`Times New Roman`' or it wont work!

Can I just iterate all the available fonts somehow and present it to them as a dropdown list so there are no spelling problems and they definitely will only be using fonts on the system?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use next code:

```
FontFamily[] ffArray = FontFamily.Families;
foreach (FontFamily ff in ffArray)
{
    //Add ff.Name to your drop-down list
}
```

Comment: Here is a Powershell one liner for convenience, especially if you just want the output: [System.Drawing.FontFamily]::Families

Answer (score 7):

Or you can just bind to it directly:

`<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}" />`

Answer (score 2):

I have font lists in several spots within my application so I like to 
load the list once and reuse the list to bind to the controls.

```
public List<string> GetFontFamilies()
{
    List<string> fontfamilies = new List<string>();                                   
    foreach (FontFamily family in FontFamily.Families)
    {
        fontfamilies.Add(family.Name);
    }
    return fontfamilies;       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the same as Gary's answer but a little more compact:

```
public static readonly List<string> FontNames = FontFamily.Families.Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```